# How to specify generic type parameter to implement equality operators in .NET6?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Is it possible to implement something like this in .NET 6? Currently im getting an error.

```
public interface IStore<TModel, TKey> where TModel: IEntity<TKey> where TKey : IEqualityOperators<TKey,TKey>
{
    public IEnumerable<TModel> GetAll();
    //default implementation
    TModel GetById(TKey id) => GetAll().Where(x => x.Id == id); //error here cuz no == operator
}
```

I wonder if i misunderstood something? So my point is that i want to express that TKey must implement equality operator and than i want to use it in my implementation.

Comment: You can't, but you might be able to use `x.Equals(id)`.

Comment: `where TKey : IEquatable<T>` maybe? Then you can use `Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id))`

Comment: Checking - you have definitely enabled the preview/experimental features, as well as targetting .NET 6?

Comment: Might want to add a link to [Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/#generic-math) since other commenters appear not to be aware of it.

Comment: It is true, I wasn't aware of Generic Math, but in the description and example, they only mention using operators on generic types, and that it was possible because of the ability to use static abstracts in interfaces. They show no usage like the above in an interface.

Comment: @TJRockefeller - [default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-methods) are even older